# Call array by using variable value of option selected

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, select

I have some arrays defined in js, I want to use the variable's value from selected option to select which array should I select.

I tried using this:

```
//code HTML
<select id="bank">
     <option value="ACB">ACB</option>
     <option value="SCB">SCB</option>
</select>

<select id="month">
     <option value="1">1 month</option>
     <option value="2">2 month</option>
     <option value="3">3 month</option>
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

```
// JS
var ACB = ["1%", "2%", "3%"];
var SCB = ["4%", "5%", "6%"];
selectElement = document.querySelector('#bank');
var a = selectElement.value; // a = ACB
selectElement = document.querySelector('#month');
var b = selectElement.value; // b = 1
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a[b]; // I was hoping result is "1%"
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Comment: was the result 2% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you would never get the expected result. Because you are taking `a[b]`. But here `a` value type would be `string` and when you use `indexing` on `strings` then you will get its `char` at that specific index.

You can achieve the expected result as

**1)** Create a `dict` which contains `both` `ACB` and `SCB` reference

```
const dict = { ACB, SCB };
```

**2)** You can get the array's value from `dict` as

```
p.textContent = dict[a][b - 1];
```

**3)** `b` index should start with zero, so to get the first result you should subtract `-1` from `b`.

```js
// JS
var ACB = ["1%", "2%", "3%"];
var SCB = ["4%", "5%", "6%"];
const dict = { ACB, SCB };

const bankEl = document.querySelector( '#bank' );
const monthEl = document.querySelector( '#month' );
const p = document.getElementById( "demo" );

const a = bankEl.value; // a = ACB
const b = monthEl.value; // b = 1

p.textContent = dict[a][b - 1]; // I was hoping result is "1%"
```

```html
<select id="bank">
  <option value="ACB">ACB</option>
  <option value="SCB">SCB</option>
</select>

<select id="month">
  <option value="1">1 month</option>
  <option value="2">2 month</option>
  <option value="3">3 month</option>
</select>

<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Have a nice day, bro @HR01M8055